# Image inside iframe rescaled cover nav

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position, nav

I have tried to reduce the size of an image inside of an iframe that I have on my website with this css class:

```
@media screen and (max-widht: 1000px) {
    .class-name {
        transform: scale(0.5);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        width: 195%;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that it covers my nav.

I am using the nav from this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g

The problem could be the position that the iframe gets when it's scaled, because when it's not, the problem isn't there; however, when I try the following:

```
position: static;
```

...the css doesn't do anything.

---

### Images

**nav bar closed**

[image: nav bar closed]

**nav bar open**

[image: nav bar open]

Comment: `position: static` won't do anything, because it already has `position: static` by default.

Comment: well yes, but even with relative it doesn't change much

Comment: If you are going to use `position`, you need to use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to actually manipulate the element. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning).

Comment: Also, have you tried modifying `transform-origin`?

Comment: i don't want the element to move, i want it to hide when the navbar comes out

Comment: Please add screenshots of what it currently looks like.

Comment: about transform-oring, yes but i want it at 0 0

Comment: i have the screenshot how do i add them to the comments?

Comment: Edit into your question. There should be an image upload feature when you're editing.

Comment: i guess i did it :D

Comment: Have you tried adding `z-index: 1;` to the navbar container, so that it overlays the images?

Comment: it worked, thak you a lot

Comment: I should probably post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the navigation content overlay the images by applying `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;` to the navigation content:

```
.navigation-content {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    ...
}
```